# Apple TVML loop data (for, foreach, etc)

Tags: tvos, tvml, tvjs

After spending around seven days with TVML, TVJS and tvOS, I finally managed to create a simple application. However, I have two problems:

1. I want to load my content from a Node.js server. It will be received as a JSON file so I guess it might be changed or converted for TVML templates.
2. How I can make a loop to load data (which has been returned from server) in XML template?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this repo. It should get you started. https://github.com/2metres/jade-tvml

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [atvjs](https://github.com/emadalam/atvjs) framework, you can easily create and navigate to dynamic pages which are regenerated while navigating.

```
ATV.Page.create({
    name: 'home',
    url: 'path/to/your/api/that/returns/json',
    template: your_template_function
});
// navigate to your page
ATV.Navigation.navigate('home');
```

You can have a look at the port of the tvml catalog sample code re-written using [atvjs](https://github.com/emadalam/atvjs) framework. https://github.com/emadalam/tvml-catalog-using-atvjs